# A size of a data that actually was read

Tags: python, python-2.7

I read a part of a file:

```
size_to_read = 999999
with open(file_name, "r") as f:
  read_part = f.read(size_to_read)
```

How do I know the size of a data (`read_part`) that actually was read in case if a size of a file is less than `size_to_read`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply check the length of the string with the built in len function:

```
size_to_read = 999999  
with open(file_name, "r") as f:  
  read_part = f.read(size_to_read)  
  if(not len(read_part) == size_to_read):
    eol_reached_unexpectedly()
```

Comment: Technically, if file size is exactly `size_to_read` then your code won't call `eol_reached` while actually you have read all data.

Comment: Forgot about the `!=` operator?

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`f.tell()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tell#file.tell) and comparing the result to `size_to_read`?